# html string concatenation Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

I have this

```
html += "<li><a href='#' onclick=viewResult(" +  my.ResultString + ") data-toggle='modal'>" + "View result" + "</a></li>";
```

But javascript throw error, any way to make the string works inside this?

Comment: Just don't do it this way at all. You're bound to run into quoting problems. Use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach a click handler to your element

Comment: What error is the error? what is the value of `my.ResultString`

Answer (score 0):

A string literal might be userful.
Note that we are passing a quoted string into the `viewResult()` function.

```
 html += `<li>
    <a href='#' onclick="viewResult('${my.ResultString}')" data-toggle='modal'>
       View result
   </a>
   </li>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way, then you need to enclose onclick attribute's value within quotes, and I changed your **li** tag quotes to single quote so that it's easier to embed something.

```
html += '<li><a href='#' onclick="viewResult(' +  my.ResultString + ')" data-toggle='modal'>View result</a></li>';
```

Although I would prefer to use string literals:

```
html += `<li><a href='#' onclick="viewResult(${my.ResultString})" data-toggle='modal'>View result</a></li>`;
```

This makes your code look so elegant and it's easier for you to keep track of whatever you are embedding without the use of **+** symbols and **different quotes** that makes it all a mess.

Comment: javascript support string literal?

Comment: @superbird, Yes javascript does support string literal.